# Wrong Output is generated Unable to get correct output

Tags: python-2.7

```
import re

NameAge =  '''
Janice is 22 and Theon is 33
Gabriel is 44 and Joey is 21
'''

names = re.findall (r'[A-Z][a-z]*', NameAge)
age = re.findall(r'\d{2}', NameAge)


ageDict = {}

x = 0

for eachname in names:

    ageDict[eachname] = age[0]
    x+=1

print(ageDict)
```

Output:
{'Gabriel': '22', 'Janice': '22', 'Joey': '22', 'Theon': '22'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are fetching first element of age. You have to go for age[x].

```
NameAge =  '''
Janice is 22 and Theon is 33
Gabriel is 44 and Joey is 21
'''
names = re.findall (r'[A-Z][a-z]*', NameAge)
age = re.findall(r'\d{2}', NameAge)
ageDict = {}
x = 0
for eachname in names:
   ageDict[eachname] = age[x]
   x+=1

print(ageDict)
```

output:  {'Gabriel': '44', 'Janice': '22', 'Joey': '21', 'Theon': '33'}

Answer (score 1):

You're always getting age[0]. You should change it to age[x]